# front end user interface for postgresql remote users

Tags: postgresql, frontend

I'm using scalegrid to host a postgresql database for work. We have about 15 people whom all live remotely. What is the best way for me to have them interface with the database to input information and run reports? I'm not sure if there is a program for this or if I need to write one in C# or such.

Comment: Do you just want a GUI where then can manage the database (like an administrator) and enter the information freely through either editing cells or running queries? If so why not just have them use pgAdmin?

Comment: If you want to do this at all, then why not just let them choose there own favorite tool?  psql, dbeaver, jetbrains, datagrip, pgadmin4, etc.

Comment: I was thinking something like a form, that is user friendly for people who arent techy. Like how one can make a form for acccess, hit a save button and it saves the info to the database.